# Is it possible to perform encrypted telephonic calls in Android?

Tags: encryption, android

When I say that I need to perform encrypted telephonic calls to another person then please understand that I do not want an encrypted VoIP call which is routed over the internet. What I want to achieve is an Android application which could encrypt the real telephonic call. In other words that application should also work even when you do not have internet connection in your mobile but a working sim card. Is it possible to achieve the same in Android?

Comment: Hi @schroeder . To me it seemed like this question could be considered as a part of "web app hardening", the first option in Help Center. I am saying so because the usual phone dialer app on Android does not allow us to have an encrypted call but having a nice app which could encrypt the telephonic calls could harden the call security on Android. Am I wrong in saying so?

Comment: There is nothing about this question that is about the web, apps, or hardening, though. Cell calls go through their own communication channel.

Comment: What you are asking for is something that the cell carrier needs to have an infrastructure for. That's why Signal uses the web.